# How to only make the text of a link go down by 1px when active and not the whole line/paragraph?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a button with a simple onclick behavior so when the user clicks on it, the text is pushed down by 1px. Here is the CSS I wrote:

```
.clickhere {
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: #4679bd;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 34px;
}

.clickhere {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1.5%;
}

.clickhere:active {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that my onclick event pushes the whole line down as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/UGJHt/. I tried with other `display` properties but it pushes my "button" on a new paragraph.

Do you know how to make just my text link go down by 1px (and not the whole paragraph line) when clicking on it?

Comment: please add html to your tags, I think its related to your question ,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would have to maintain the alignment

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UGJHt/12/)

**Edited section of CSS**

```
.clickhere {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 1.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with :after and :before?

```
.clickhere {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: #4679bd;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    height: 34px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clickhere {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1.5%;
}
.clickhere:before,
.clickhere:after {
    display: none;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #4679bd;
}
.clickhere:before {
    top: -1px;
}
.clickhere:after {
   bottom: -1px; 
}
.clickhere:active:before,
.clickhere:active:after {
   display: block;
}
```

See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BHk76/).

Answer (score 0):

its easy, just put your text in a **span** tag and change its style to **position:relative** and **top:2px** when actived,
here is your html code:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi volutpat ultrices dolor, sed    tempor lorem mollis nec. Nullam consequat euismod elit a blandit. Donec tincidunt velit accumsan justo facilisis.
<a class="clickhere" href=""><span>Click here</span></a>
<br>You will be sent an email with the ultimate cheat explained.
</p>
<p>In sollicitudin ut diam eget venenatis. Duis semper eros eget elit blandit, sit amet blandit enim faucibus.</p>
<p>Aenean lacus neque, molestie id ultricies in, molestie et ante.</p>
<p>Suspendisse sit amet sollicitudin arcu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
```

and here is your css code:

```
.clickhere {
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    background: #4679bd;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 34px;
}

.clickhere {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1.5%;
}

.clickhere span:active {
    position:relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

hope be useful